# How to map two folders to an another one on Windows?

Tags: windows, directory-junction

I need to show content of 2 directories on another one on the same machine by the easiest way. Third folder should be looks like it has all files and subdirectories of the source. Files should be accessible as usual. It is not a good idea to copy all data or to make link for each file/subfolder. Files may be changed or list of them may be changed too. It is possible on Windows?

Comment: Not going to happen on Windows without some third party (non free) utility that has that function. It would be simulated environment at best in my opinion. There is no utility in the pure NTFS to make such directories. Custom script that creates symlinks to files in both directories and creates them in single directory would be my best guess, although you will have a delay due to scheduler running periodically, unless you want it to run constantly and monitor the directories - this would minimize the delay. TL;DR not in pure Windows/NTFS unless you like Powershell Scripts etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible. The nearest you can get is either to use a "library" (W7+) and add both folders to it or create a parent folder and link the two folders into the new parent so they at least show up in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I put here an answer, but it wouldn't help anybody, because it is hard in realization. It is possible to do by two ways:

1. Write application which would scan files and file operations on target folders and show result in another one by copying files or making symlinks in realtime.
2. Make a driver that would do the same. It is more reliable method because driver can monitor more file system events and respond to them without delay to user.